# Set display color of transparecy in PNG

Tags: png, transparency

Is it possible to set the color that the transparency of a PNG should be displayed with, if viewed standalone?

My motivation is: if I have a PNG with white text and transparency and I show this image on a website with dark background, I want to link the image to the image itself. If I click on that link, I want the PNG to be shown on dark background. If I have a PNG with black text on transparency, I want to show the image on white background, if viewed standalone.

If this is possible, I reckon the information must be present in the PNG file itself. How would I set the wanted color in, say Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the PNG transparent background with a colored one open the PNG in Photoshop, create a new layer (Layer menu > New > Layer) and fill it with the desired color using the Paint Bucket tool. In the Layers panel drag the filled layer under the PNG and then save it.

P.S. If the PNG layer is locked, double click on it to unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, use [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) to modify or add the bKGD chunk.